# Webhosting with custom database choice

Tags: web-hosting, custom-server-controls, orientdb

I've asked this question elsewhere: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/28320/webhosting-with-custom-database-choice but was hoping that someone here might be able to point me in the right direction too... Does anybody know of any web hosting which will support OrientDB?

Comment: You forgot to actually ask a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there is only NuvolaBase that offers it: [www.nuvolabase.com](http://www.nuvolabase.com)